# How to use join to combined two data frame by two variables and keep different rows with second variable

Tags: r

I want to combine two data frames by both ID and date variables, and want to keep all IDs from two data, and dates from two data.

examples:

data A:

```
ID  date  V1          
1    1     a       
1    4     b       
2    9     d     
3    10    e
```

data B:

```
ID  date  X               
1   1     24                 
1   2     30  
1   4     15   
2   2     40    
2   5     10    
2   7     12
```

results:

```
ID  date  X    V1           
1   1     24   a               
1   2     30   NA     
1   4     15   b     
2   2     40   NA        
2   5     10   NA       
2   7     12   NA       
2   9     NA   d      
3   10    NA   e
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("ID", "date")) %>%
  arrange(ID, date)

  ID date   V1  X
1  1    1    a 24
2  1    2 <NA> 30
3  1    4    b 15
4  2    2 <NA> 40
5  2    5 <NA> 10
6  2    7 <NA> 12
7  2    9    d NA
8  3   10    e NA
```